# С какой буквы писать название Венис-Бич?

Tags: топонимика

Существует такой пляж в Лос-Анджелесе - Венис-Бич. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет корректно Венис-Бич или Венис-бич?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §169. Примечание 3. Некоторые иноязычные родовые наименования, входящие в географическое название, но не употребляющиеся в русском языке как нарицательные существительные, пишутся с прописной буквы. Однако иноязычные родовые наименования, которые могут употребляться в русском языке как нарицательные существительные, пишутся со строчной буквы.

Однако, тут мы работаем не столько с русским правописанием, сколько с англо-русской транскрипцией.

Обращаясь к "Инструкции по русской передаче английских географических названий"<sup>2</sup> 1975 года:

> §65. Географические термины транскрибируются независимо от того, чем выражена определяющая часть названия, если они несут в себе специфическую характеристику объекта.

Правило ссылается на приложение 2, где присутствует строка:

> beach<sup>+</sup> | бич | пляж, отлогий морской берег

И сноска:

> Термины, помеченные знаком <sup>+</sup>, транскрибируются всегда в соответствии с §65.

В этой же инструкции идет и указание написания:

> §69. Сложные географические названия, пишущиеся по-английски слитно, передаются также слитно. Составные названия, пишущиеся по-английски раздельно, передаются через дефис, причем каждая основная часть названия (существительное, прилагательное, числительное) пишется с прописной буквы.

Соответственно:

*Венис-Бич*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.
2. Инструкция по русской передаче английских географических названий. Ред. Л. И. Аненберг. — М., 1975.